# Can not pull or merge git. “Working copy has uncommited changes”

Tags: git

How can I fix pull issue.
When I pull from xcode then it is giving error "**Can not pull working copy has uncommited changes"**

Comment: Try commiting your code before performing your pull. It  always happens when you have done some modifications locally without commiting them.

Comment: Stash, pull, pop stash

Comment: Thanks for reply, we are two developer and working on same project. My friend commited all code on bitbucket, now I want to pull for merge all code then it's giving error pull time.

Comment: Before you try to pull the code, make sure you have add-commited your local changes.

Comment: @7vikram7 I am able to pull updated code from bitbucket in mac laptop(mac pro) but not able in mac mini.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do commit or to stash your code.

#### 1. Commit

If you have changes and you cant pull you can simply commit your changes.

```
# add the desired files to the index
git add .

# commit your changes
git commit -m "Message..."

# now pull your changes
git pull origin <branch>
```

#### 2. Stash

```
# stash your changes and pull them back later on
# add the [-u] flag for untracked files if needed
git stash save <name> 

# pull the new content
git pull origin <branch>

# get back the code which you stashed
git stash pop
```

Comment: I am able to pull updated code from bitbucket in mac laptop(mac pro) using Xcode but not able in mac mini.